# While parsing xml, getAttribute gets some of the items and not others

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname, getattribute

Here is a sample of the XML:

```
<markers><marker name="Faulkner State Community College" lat="30.853801" lng="-87.776692" type="PS" number="279" address="CFOT, CPCT" /></markers>
```

The parser is picking up name, lat, lan, and address. It's not picking up type and number. The output for type and number is undefined. I don't need them converted to anything other than a string.

Here is my code:

```
var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
        var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
        var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
        var type = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("type");
        var number = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("number");
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
            parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));


        createMarker(latlng, name, address, type, number);
   }
```

And here is the code for 'createMarker', just in case:

```
function createMarker(latlng, name, address, type, number) {
    var html = "<font face=\"Arial\" size=\"2\"><b><a href=\"school.php?school_number=" + number + "\">" + name + "</a></b> <br/>Certifications: " + address + "<br/>School #: " + number + "</font>";
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng,
    icon: customIcon(type)
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  markers.push(marker);
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure jQuery can parse XML strings like this.  You might look into that.

Comment: @AdamRackis http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif

Comment: @austincheney - seen it - pretty funny.  Surely you'd agree that suggesting jQuery for parsing big XML string is a lot more justifiable—and sensible—than suggesting it to add two numbers together.

Comment: @austincheney - see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/471615/352552  :)

Comment: I completely disagree with that extremely popular stackoverflow link.  I can do any job that a jQuery user can do, but jQuery users are completely incapable of doing my job even though its still just JavaScript.  I shouldn't complain tho, as long as the popular opinion remains the wrong opinion I will continue to be paid big bucks and have stellar job security.

Comment: @austincheney - the **average** jQuery user is probably pretty dim, but that's only because jQuery is so easy to use that dom manipulation is suddenly available to novice devs—a good thing.  Don't think for a second there aren't plenty of us jQuery users who understand full well JS closures, inheritance, hoisting, what `this` means in a method vs a function, etc etc etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two sets of the markerNodes parsing and was editing the wrong set.